# Matplotlib grouped data clustered bar chart in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dictionary of values (`drug`) as follows:

```
{0: {0: 100.0, 1: 0.41249706379061035, 2: 5.144449764434768, 3: 31.078456871927678}, 1: {0: 100.0, 1: 0.6688801420346955, 2: 77.32360971119694, 3: 78.15132480853421}, 2: {0: 100.0, 1: 136.01949766418852, 2: 163.4967732211563, 3: 146.7726208999281}}
```

It contains 3 drug types, then the efficacy of that drug type in 4 different concentrations.

I'm trying to make a clustered bar chart which compares the 3 drugs against each other like this:

[image]

Currently, my code is the following:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.35
ind = np.arange(3)

for x in range(3):
    ax.bar(ind + (width * x), drug[x].values(), width, bottom=0)

ax.set_title('Drug efficacy')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(list(string.ascii_uppercase[0:drugCount]))

ax.autoscale_view()

plt.show()
```

I have adapted the code from [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/units/bar_unit_demo.html) guide, but am having multiple problems.

I think the main reason is that the data used in the example is such that values in one group correspond to the same colour rather than the same cluster.

How can I adapt this code such that it will plot the efficacy of each drug in the 4 different concentrations in isolation compared to the other drugs?

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(drug_dict, orient='index').plot.bar()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to normalize your values by column, which can be done using `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

df = pd.DataFrame(drug)
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df))
df.T.plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll give that a go - any idea why 0 does not show as 100 in this situation yet 2 does for drug 2?

Comment: Not sure If i get it correctly, but when you normalize the values to 0-1 the lowest value becomes 0. Thus in drug 2 the first one becomes 0.